# vscode on Spring Boot + Kotlin + Gralde project make

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, gradle, visual-studio-code, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I want to configure gradle project using Spring Boot + kotlin in vscode.

I tried to configure the project by referring to several sites, but it didn't work.

May I know the link or site of the guideline document?

It has been confirmed that the configuration of the vscode + java + spring boot + gradle project works normally.

The specs of my laptop are a bit too heavy to run intellij.

Please help me configure vscode + spring boot + kotlin + gradle project in my laptop.

Comment: Have you tried this one?: https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-boot-kotlin/

Comment: You may be able to elicit more constructive responses if you can clarify your meaning of "it didn't work".

Comment: Does ./gradlew bootrun works from terminal ? or you want to run with a button click from vscode ? What have you done ? And what is your desired outcome ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, `vscode` + `spring boot` + `java` + `gradle` is possible,

however I know that `vscode` + `spring boot` + `kotlin` + `gradle` is not supported.

https://www.python2.net/questions-1080751.htm

Comment: Is this still true?

Comment: I think so, kotlin if developed by  JetBrains and they prefer to give support to Intellij that is the oficil IDE for kotlin.   We can use for a simple kotlin project, but with spring boot I do not found any solution yet.